# Unpredictable Selenium WebDriver Behavior

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have several selenium tests that I run. Today, as I was working on them, several kept failing. They had previously been passing. I investigated the issue a little further in the code and found everything to be in place. I ran them again with; they failed.

I did this for a bit, tweaking the code here and there, trying to figure out why they would be failing. Then, out of frustration, I reverted my changes and "helped" the test along by clicking on the element it said it couldn't find (clearly, it was there and my code was looking for the correct element). The test passed. I then re-ran the test without helping it along. All of the tests passed.  I've run into this situation before, and usually closing Visual Studio and starting fresh seemed to do the trick.

This behavior is not consistant and is a little frustrating. How can I avoid situations like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are thousands different reasons why the tests can fail. Specially the UI test is the most flakiest kind of test. However, I am not sure it has anything to do with closing and reopening the visual studio. Even if that the reason, you probably want to investigate the root cause or how that is related to test. I personally use visual studio and never ran into such scenario. 
Since you mentioned, the elements are there I think it is the element load issues. You may find the [explicit](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) wait helpful in that case. Ajax calls and refresh the part of the DOM is a killer for UI test. Without knowing any detail or seeing the test code I would suggest you to find element with essential explicit wait or provide the test code you are having trouble with for further help.

Comment: When you look for a solution it's good a practice to provide test codes and stack trace to get the answer quickly and accurately.